# Authenticated user field in email shows primary email when using aliases

Tags: email

So I have an email with a custom domain and when I send an email using an alias,
my primary email is shown in the source of the mail in the field Received:(authenticated user my@primaryemail.tld).
In all the other fields the alias email is shown.
I've set up dkim, spf and dmarc.
Is this how it's supposed to work or am I doing something wrong?
I'm using gandi mail as email provider.

Comment: This sounds like you're asking about some piece of software or third-party service. If so, the question may belong on https://superuser.com or https://webapps.stackexchange.com rather than here, but either way you're going to have to edit in some more details.

Comment: @IMSoP I've edited with further details.